# Apache route subdomain to nginx on port?

Tags: apache, nginx

I have a server running CentOS 7 that has an Apache web-server running on port 80.  I am also using a common open-source Git project called GitLab, which uses the nginx web-server instead of Apache.  I have configured GitLab's nginx to run on port 4444.

I have a subdomain "git.mydomain.com" that I would like to forward to "mydomain.com:4444" however I would like the URL to continue saying "git.mydomain.com".

I belived that I need to have an Apache VirtualHost file, however I'm not sure what to do.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do so?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You would indeed need a `git.mydomain.com` VirtualHost with a proxy/reverse proxy directive. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html